# Parentheses (), single square brackets[], double square brackets[[]], curly brackets{}

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and find it confusing when to use the

- Parentheses `()`
- single square brackets `[]`
- double square brackets `[[]]`
- curly brackets `{}`
- `:` single colon
- `::` double colons
- `.` period
- `_` underscore

I understand `()` are for tuples, `[]` for data frame and list, `{}` for dictionary, `:` for indexing, slicing, but to use and mix them together in a line, it starts to get confusing.

Is it common for beginner to get confused on how to use these? Is there a pattern to recognise?

Comment: If you understand each of them separately, then combining them becomes clearer after you practice a little. There's no real question here.

Comment: Parentheses *are not for tuples*. `x = 1, 2` is a perfectly valid tuple

Answer (score 2):

As with all programming languages. There is no pattern here but a syntax. Hopefully as you write more and more code in Python you would get familiar with it. But it is similar to most other languages like Java or C++.

```
s1=[1,2,3,4] #this is a list in python. 
s2=(1,2,3) #this is a tuple. 
s3=s1[1:] #this take the list elements starting from index 1 to end element. 
s4=[[1,2],[1]] #this is a list of list.
```

Hopefully, this helps. Python is one of the easiest language to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy, here we go. But better read documentation [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

parentheses () - when you are calling for function or class methoh - x = add_something(2,3),or a set which has only unique values `s = (1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5)`

single square brackets [] - 1D list, they can be mutable and multi type - `[1,2,3,420, 'smokeeveryday']`

double square brackets [[]] = 2D list... - `[[11,9]['Denamrk', "dosen't", 'exists'],[55378008]]`

curly brackets {} = dictionaries, each has a key and an answer to that key, answers can be other types like list-  `{ "key": 'answer', 69: 'nice', 'list': [1, 42, 12, 233]}`

single colon : = when you want to get all values from(for example) list, you can do `x = lol[:5]` which will return all values from start to 5-th index(without 5-th)
double - for all values

underscore is really to big subject to touch it here

peroid - when you have object of a class, you can call method of this class by adding peroid after object, smth like `skynet.kill_humans()` but as above, it's too big to properly explain here. it's base of whole OOP.